# Adding bootstrap in WordPress theme seems to override nav styles

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a Divi child theme on a website. I added Bootstrap to create a contact form. However, as soon as I enqueued the style and script using wp_enqueue_style and wp_enqueue_script the top nav got some extra padding and a background color on hover.

You can see the differences by loading the [live site](http://www.osiristours.com/) and the [dev site](http://dev-osiris-tours.pantheonsite.io/) and comparing them.

Here is the enqueuing code I have in my functions.php file in the child theme. When I run it and view source, it does appear to put the main style.css after the bootstrap css, which is what I understand is necessary to ensure style.css has the specificity here. What am I missing?

```
// Enqueue Bootstrap for modal popup contact form
function wpbootstrap_scripts_with_jquery()
{
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpbootstrap_scripts_with_jquery' );

// BEGIN ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION
// AUTO GENERATED - Do not modify or remove comment markers above or below:

if ( !function_exists( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css' ) ):
    function chld_thm_cfg_parent_css() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent', trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'style.css', array(  ) );
    }
endif;
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css' );

if ( !function_exists( 'child_theme_configurator_css' ) ):
    function child_theme_configurator_css() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'chld_thm_cfg_separate', trailingslashit( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ) . 'ctc-style.css', array( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent','divi-style','et-shortcodes-css','et-shortcodes-responsive-css','magnific-popup' ) );
    }
endif;
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_theme_configurator_css' );

// END ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION
```

Comment: looks like you may have matching classes and only one class wins. To fix this -- Option [1] -- in the CSS proprerties add (!mportant) to the ones you dont want to be changed so they have priority over the ones that are messing with the styles. eg (color: blue !important) -- so that means you need inspect the css code on the browsrer to see what CSS is crossed out for the elements, edit the css file and add (!important) to each one -- Option [2] it may be safe to just delete the CSS thats has priority over the other CSS file but if you dont know whats going on i keep in and go with option 1

Comment: check here for further info -- https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Comment: one last thing -- you will need to download the unminified version of bootstrap css and amend that -- http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css -- you can minify it later when you are done Online. https://cssminifier.com/

Comment: If I download the unminified version so I can amend it, won't I then need to  enqueue that as a local copy only and not via CDN?

Comment: I dont know how Wordpress works. Can you load a local CSS file or does it have to be from a remote server?

Comment: I can do either. But the idea of using the CDN was to save on the page speed because the CDN would be edge-cached geographically nearest to the user requesting the page.

Comment: It doesnt work like that. CDN's are there so the servers are always up and so you have 100% assurance the files will download. Once you download the css either local or cdn files the next time it will get them from the browsers cache anyway so its faster. if you delete the cache  then it will reload them again. You have one more Choice. If you can use (<style> .. <style>) in your page(s) then copy the styles  i.e add the whole style(s) from Bootstrap (the affected ones) and add (!mportant)

Answer (score 0):

I have came accross this situation just recently and I have found that:

1. You must use `wp_enqueue_scripts` to add script
2. Keep a close eyes on the version of the [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/).
3. Have version for `wp_enqueue_style` higher then your regular scripts. Note  `1.0.3` in code below.

My full working code is which is not overridden by other classes

```
function wp_enquene_bulma_css() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bulma', '/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen-child/css/bulma.min.css', false, '1.0.3', 'all' );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_enquene_bulma_css');
```